# PPSS shell script

Tags: linux, macos, parallel-processing, sox

I made a simple shell script to process mp3 files with SoX.

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do sox "$f" "${f%%.mp3}S.mp3" silence 1 0.02 1% -1 0.02 1%; done
```

The syntax should be like this:

```
sox in.wav out.wav silence 1 0.1 1% -1 0.1 1%
```

It will remove silence from the files I have in a folder, and create a new file with an "X" at the end (to distinguish from the original). I saved the script in my /bin folder and it works fine.

However, now I want to use it with PPSS, in order to run 8 instances in parallel. I cannot seem to get it working though, in the log file the error I keep getting is this error in the logs:

/usr/local/bin/ppss: line 2283: soxy.sh/Users/marw/Downloads/testfolder//ppss_dir/job_log/_Users_marw_Downloads_testfolder__10_audio_mp3: No such file or directory

Status:     FAILURE
Total processing time (hh:mm:ss): 00:00:01

The PPSS syntax should be like this:

```
|P|P|S|S| Distributed Parallel Processing Shell Script 2.97

usage: /usr/local/bin/ppss [[ -d <sourcedir> | -f <sourcefile> ]]  [[ -c '<command> "$ITEM"' ]] 
                 [[ -C <configfile> ]] [[ -j ]] [[ -l <logfile> ]] [[ -p <# jobs> ]] 
                 [[ -q ]] [[ -D <delay> ]] [[ -h ]] [[ --help ]] [[ -r ]] [[ --daemon ]] 

Examples:
                 /usr/local/bin/ppss -d /dir/with/some/files -c 'gzip '
                 /usr/local/bin/ppss -d /dir/with/some/files -c 'cp "$ITEM" /tmp' -p 2
                 /usr/local/bin/ppss -f <file> -c 'wget -q -P /destination/directory "$ITEM"' -p 10
```

I'm new to shell scripting, forgive me if it's a stupid question. My OS is MacOS 10.11.5.

This is what I'm trying with PPSS:

```
ppss -d /Users/marw/Downloads/testfolder -c 'soxy.sh'
```

Maybe I have to write the my original script differently? It works fine without PPSS though.

EDIT:

I got a debug log here: http://pastebin.com/wak47rf8

Comment: I deleted my answer after rereading your post. It appears that `ppss` is passing the your script "soxy.sh" into the directory path you gave it, although I am not familiar with "ppss" and how it works. I will ponder this for a few before posting again.

Comment: ok cool :) thanks. BTW, it doesn't have to be PPSS, but this is what I found searching on Stackoverflow. I just want to run the script in parallel, so I can use 8 cores instead of 1.

Comment: I found the answer, I had to leave a trailing space after "soxy.sh', like this 'soxy.sh '. I just tried it this way and it works.

Comment: Glad to hear it :).

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question in case other people stumble onto this exact issue as you did

Answer (score 1):

The -c argument has to have a trailing space at the end. This works:

```
ppss -d /Users/marw/Downloads/testfolder -c 'soxy.sh '
```

Whereas this does not work:

```
ppss -d /Users/marw/Downloads/testfolder -c 'soxy.sh'
```

I got this from the PPSS wiki on Github:

> The -c option specifies the command that will be executed by PPSS in
>   parallel for each file within the directory specified by -d. In this
>   example the command has a trailing space, which is necessary since the
>   command will expand to 'gzip example.tar' when executed. If the space
>   is omitted, an error will occur.

Comment: Consider using GNU `parallel` or OSX/GNU `xargs` instead if you don't need this weird and fragile script's ssh functionality

Comment: I'm trying with parallel but having some trouble, however xargs does not seem to be a parallelising tool, I tried reading the man page but can't figure it out. PPSS also seems fragile to me but it's the only one I got to work. I just need to parallelise SoX, so that I can process one file for each core. I'm very new to CLI tools so I might be missing something very basic.

Comment: OSX and GNU `xargs` have `-P` to parallelize.